# Hi, I have to pass some code over a sticky navbar from javascript to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, navbar, sticky

It is a navbar that I originally did in javascript (in a separate folder with pure html, css and js that did work) but I want to change it to typescript to work with angular.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

let navbar = document.getElementById("menu-bottom");
let sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

or what happens is that when I pass it to typescript it marks an error in the `navbar` since it says that it is null (I guess because of the `getElementById`) but I don't know how to change it to make it work.

Comment: The title should give a short summary of the actual problem -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

let navbar = document.getElementById("menu-bottom");

// Check if the 'navbar' is not null
if (!navbar) throw new Error("#menu-bottom should be defined")

let sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

## Details

You can take a look with [the return value of getElementById() definition in MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). It said:

> An Element object describing the DOM element object matching the specified ID, **or null if no matching element was found in the document**.

Therefore, when "#menu-bottom" is not presented in the DOM tree, it returned `null`. If you are really sure that it should never be `null`, it is better to write an assertion like this:

```js
if (!navbar) throw new Error("#menu-bottom should be defined")
```

It would be better to load the script after the DOM content were completely loaded:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { /* your code goes here */ });
```

Comment: This is probably one of the best answers I have read from a new contributor. You nailed it!

Comment: @Igor Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error conveys that `navbar` could be null and that you should check for a value before using it in such a way that it would throw an error that 'cannot read property 'offsetTop' of undefined'.

```
let navbar = document.getElementById("menu-bottom");
if (navbar) {
  let sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
}
```